# Understanding Scala Code

Tags: regex, scala

I am learning Scala.

Could anyone please explain the below piece of code?
I am trying to understand, but can't..

```
def resolveDollarVar(sqlStr: String, vars: Map[String, String]): String = {
  val varPattern = new scala.util.matching.Regex("""(\$\{(\S+?)\})""", "fullVar", "value")
  varPattern replaceAllIn (sqlStr, m => {
    try {
      vars(m.group("value"))
    }
    catch {
      case e: NoSuchElementException => throw new NoSuchElementException("Error: " + m.group("fullVar") + " cannot be resolved")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: please explain what specifically you are having trouble with

Comment: I don't understand the word 'm' and what is vars(m.group("value"))? I know vars is a Map variable, what this function "(m.group("value")" does on Map vaiable?

Comment: `m`  is the match data object, `value`  is the text captured with `(\S+?)`, and that is used as a key to get the corresponding value from the Map.

Comment: @Jee please edit that information into your question.  You can look into the signature for the relevant method, `replaceAlIn` and see if that helps you at all

Answer (score 1):

A quick visit to [the relevant scaladoc page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#replaceAllIn(target:CharSequence,replacer:scala.util.matching.Regex.Match=%3EString):String) reveals the following:

> `def replaceAllIn(target: CharSequence, replacer: (Match) ⇒ String): String`
>
> Replaces all matches using a replacer function. The replacer function
>       takes a scala.util.matching.Regex.Match so that extra information can be
>       obtained from the match. For example:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
val datePattern = new Regex("""(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""", "year", "month", "day")
val text = "From 2011-07-15 to 2011-07-17"
val repl = datePattern replaceAllIn (text, m => s"${m group "month"}/${m group "day"}")
```

> In the replacement String, a dollar sign ($) followed by a number will be
>       interpreted as a reference to a group in the matched pattern, with numbers
>       1 through 9 corresponding to the first nine groups, and 0 standing for the
>       whole match. Any other character is an error. The backslash (\) character
>       will be interpreted as an escape character and can be used to escape the
>       dollar sign. Use Regex.quoteReplacement to escape these characters.

So `m` is a `Match` passed to the `replacer` lambda. `group()` is a method to retrieve named groups from the `Match` parameter. `"value"` is the label assigned to one of the two capture groups in the regex pattern.

Thus:

1. Use Regex to parse the input `sqlStr`. Capture the substring of interest and label it "value".
2. Retrieve the string labeled "value" and use it to index the `vars` Map.
3. `replaceAllIn` will replace the substring labeled "value" with the string retrieved from the `vars` Map.